# Determining Which Table the Result Came From

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a couple tables that I'm joining together so I can form all of the relevenat results into a news feed of recent activity. The only problem I'm having is figuring out which  table the information is coming from.

```
$recentActivity = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN market 
ON members.id = market.user 
LEFT JOIN sales 
ON members.id = sales.uid 
WHERE members.id='$id'
");
```

I'm then running a while loop

```
<? while ($recent = mysql_fetch_assoc($recentActivity)) { ?>
```

If the result in the loop comes from the market table I would like to be able to echo "market" or something like that and do the same if it comes from the sales table.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The data is coming from the table that results from the join. Each column of that table comes from a well-defined source table, but unless we see the table structures and know which particular piece of data you want to know about, there's nothing more to be said.

Comment: Question does not make sense. What do you mean by "which table the information is coming from"? The resultset arises by joining 3 tables. Each row takes information from between 1 and 3 of those tables (because you used an outer join - you can check to see whether there were no corresponding rows from the table on the right by checking whether columns are `NULL`).

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Let me try to re-example it a bit.

I have two tables, sales and downloads. I'm trying to create a news feed of activity based on those tables by joining the two into a long feed. The problem I'm having is in the while loop is telling if it came from the sales table or the download table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. The only possible way is to explicitly specify aliases for all (necessary) `market` table fields. Like:

```
SELECT members.*,
       market.id AS market_id,
       market.foobar AS market_foobar
```

etc. The same with `sales` table

Comment: Each column of the join table comes from a well-defined source table. The only exception is join columns, in which case the identical data is present in that column for the joined source tables.

Answer (score 0):

There's this convention that a lot of people use. If I have a table, Users:

```
--------------------------------
| user_username   | varchar(20) |
| user_email      | varchar(40) |
| user_phone      | varchar(13) |
---------------------------------
```

This allows you do have joins and know specifically what table that data came from. It's a sort of namespacing.

If you can rename your fields in the table, I would heavily consider it.